# Open another app in-app, then close and return to calling app

Tags: ipad, document, in-app

Have searched high and low and it seems that this is not possible by any conventional means, but, does anyone know if it it's possible to:

1) Open a file (eg Pages) via an app (App 1).  This will launch the Pages app on iPad.

2) Edit the doc, save and close

3) The close action returns the user to the calling app (App 1).

Can it be done?

Thanks for any help or pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done on iOS because of restrictions and the sandboxing-concept of the OS (at least without jailbreaking the device).

Comment: That's what I thought.  Thanks. Is it not possible with URL schemes at all?

Comment: You can do some stuff with URL schemes. But the other app (you'd like to open) must support open your doc, save and close as a part of the URL scheme implementation. I think it would be possible if you can create / define the app you'd like to open. But for "Pages" from Apple: impossible.